# How type ignorance is internally implemented in PHP

Tags: php, internals

How is type ignorance implemented in PHP? For example, I can write the function:

```
function min($n, $m){
   if ($n<$m) return $n;
   return $m;
}
```

Then, I could use that function indifferently with integer, real or even string. I believe this is possible because PHP passes pointers instead of real variables (or reference to variables). Am I right? Can someone point me out a good lecture about internal implementation of PHP or a good explanation of how thing are made?

*I should add that I am much interested into the way PHP interpreter make it work. Thank for the answers that were provided until now.*

Comment: PHP has no pointers. Only "references", which are similar BUT NOT THE SAME as pointers. PHP also typecasts silently and on-demand, reducing the need to know WHAT type something is in most circumstances. "it just (usually) works"

Answer (score 2):

Its because PHP is dynamic. Things are passed by value in PHP. Its called duck typing.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_PHP

Answer (score 0):

By default, PHP passes variables by value, not by reference. It is possible to pass by reference by changing `function min($n,$m)` to `function min(&$n, &$m)`.  For more on pass-by-reference, check out [this link on the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

This also may be helpful for you: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php